# Reset switch case value so they can enter menu input again Java

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, reset

I am using a switch statement which worked fine. But if something like an exception occurs inside the switch I want the program to return to ask for the users selection again.

I'll share some example code:

```
while (valid != true)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a Choice \n1. Choice 1. \n2. Choice 2. \n3. Choice 3.");
    int choice = getChoice();      //Get choice just returns an integer from user input.

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            //Do something
            valid = true;
            break;

        case 2:
            //Do something
            valid = true;
            break;

        case 3:
            //Do something
            valid = true;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Choice.");
    }
```

So if something went wrong and validChoice wasn't set to true. I want the user to be able to re-enter the choice but since the choice is already set. It will go to case 3 straight away.

**Some things ive tried include:**

***All of these would be done if something goes wrong.***

Setting choice to null for if it goes wrong. (Was hopeful that this would work) but java doesn't allow

Setting choice to 0 would just make it go to the default case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
            do {
                 System.out.println("Enter a Choice \n1. Choice 1. \n2. Choice 2. \n3. Choice 3.");
    int choice = getChoice();      //Get choice just returns an integer from user input.

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            //Do something
            valid = true;
            break;

        case 2:
            //Do something
            valid = true;
            break;

        case 3:
            //Do something
            valid = true;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Choice.");
            break;
    }

            } while (valid != true);
}
}
```